# ActionText stripping out iframe tag despite whitelisting them in Rails 6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix, actiontext

I'm using ActionText inside of a rails 6 application. I added custom attachments to Trix so that users can embed Vimeo and YouTube videos.

The videos are shown as expected when loaded within Trix. However, when showing them on a page using something like

```
<%= @section.content %>
```

Where `content` is my `rich_text_field`, the iframe get stripped away.

I added `iframe` to the `allowed_tags` using an initializer

```rb
#config/initializers/html_sanitizer.rb

Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.allowed_tags << 'iframe'
```

And I also tried adding this to `application.rb` as Chris Oliver from GoRails did in his Rails conf talk

```
config.to_prepare do
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags << 'iframe'
end
```

Do you have any idea as to why this is not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I use this in an initializer for other tags, which works in Rails 6:

`Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.allowed_tags.add 'iframe'`